# how does a language *know* when a list is sorted?

Tags: list, sorting

Forgive me if this question is dumb, but it occurred to me I don't know how a language knows a list is sorted or not.

Say I have a list:

```
["Apple","Apricot","Blueberry","Cardamom","Cumin"]
```

and I want to insert `"Cinnamon"`.
AFAIK The language I'm using doesn't know the list is sorted; it's just a list. And it doesn't have a "wide screen" field of view like we do, so it doesn't know where the A-chunk ends and the C-chunk begins from outside the list.  So it goes through and compares the first letter of each array string to the first letter of the insert string. If the insert char is greater, it moves to the next string. If the chars match, it moves to the next letter. If it moves on to the next string and the array's char is greater than the insert's char, then the char is inserted there.

My question is, can a language KNOW when a list is sorted?
If the process for combing through a unsorted and sorted list is the same, and the list is still iterated through, then how does sorting save time?

EDIT:
I understand that "sorting allows algorithms that rely on sorting to work"; I apologize for not making that clear. I guess I'm asking if there's anything intrinsic about sorting inside computer languages, or if it's a strategy that people built on top of it. I think it's the latter and you guys have confirmed it. A language doesn't know if it's sorting something or not, but we recognize the performance difference.

Comment: The list does not know by default. It depends on the implementation, maybe there is a flag or something. If your question is "how does a list know how to sort?" then there are several interesting things in the internet.

Comment: To the last bit of OP's words - sorting allows for algorithms like [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the key. The *language* doesn't / can't / shouldn't know whether your data structure is sorted or unsorted. In fact it doesn't even care what data structure it really is.

Now consider this: What does insertion or deletion really mean? What exact steps need to be taken to insert a new item or delete an existing one. It turns out that the exact meaning of these operations depend upon the data structure that you're using. An array will insert a new element very differently than a linked list.

So it stands to reason that these operations must be defined in the context of the data structure on which these are being applied. The *language* in general does not supply any keywords to deal with these data structures. Rather the accompanying libraries provide built-in implementations of these structures that contain methods to perform these operations.

Now to the original question: How does the language "know" if a list is sorted or not and why is it more efficient to deal with sorted lists? The answer is, as evident from what I said above, the language doesn't and shouldn't know about the internals of a list. It is the implementation of the list structure that you're using that knows if it is sorted or not, and how to insert a new node in an ordered manner. For example, a certain data structure may use an index (much like the index of a book) to locate the position of the words starting with a certain letter, thus reducing the amount of time that an unsorted list would require to traverse through the entire list, one element at a time.

Hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> can a language KNOW when a list is sorted

Do you mean a language interpreter? Of course it *can* check whether a list is sorted, simply by checking each elements is "larger" than the previous. I doubt that interpreters do this; why should they care if the list is sorted or not?

In general, if you want to insert "Cinammon" into your list, you need to either specify where to insert it, or just append it at the end. It doesn't matter to the interpreter if the list is sorted beforehand or not. It's how you use the list that determines whether a sorted list will remain sorted, and whether or not it needs to be sorted to begin with. (For example, if you try to find something in the list using a binary search, then the list must be sorted. But *you* must arrange for this to be the case).

> AFAIK The language I'm using ...

(which is?)

> ... doesn't know the list is sorted; it's just a list. And it doesn't have a "wide screen" field of view like we do, so it doesn't know where the A-chunk ends and the C-chunk begins from outside the list. So it goes through and compares the first letter of each array string to the first letter of the insert string. If the insert char is greater, it moves to the next string. If the chars match, it moves to the next letter. If it moves on to the next string and the array's char is greater than the insert's char, then the char is inserted there.

What you're saying, I think, is that it looks for the first element that is "bigger than" the one being inserted, and inserts the new element just before it. That implies that it maintains the "sorted" property of the list, if it is already sorted. This is horribly inefficient for the case of unsorted lists. Also, the technique you describe for finding the insertion point (linear search) would be inefficient, if that is truly what is happening. I would suspect that your understanding of the list/language semantics are not correct.

It would help a lot if you gave a concrete example in a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

Languages don't know such things.

Some programming languages come with a standard library containing data structures, and if they don't, you generally can link to libraries that do.

Some of those data structures may be collection types that maintain order.

So given you have a data structure that represents an ordered collection type, then it is **that data structure** that maintains the order of the collection, whenever an item is added or removed.

If you're using the most basic collection type, an array, then neither the language nor the runtime nor the data structure itself (the array) care in the slightest at what point you insert an item.